# Action<Action<string,int>> and Lambda Expression in C#

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

I've searched on this, but don't really know how to word the question to get the answer so far I can't find anything on nested actions like this with Lambda expressions. I can find lots of help on passing lambda expressions as parameters where the parameter is a delegate and in fact I'm doing that lots in my code. It's the nested lambda expression that's giving me problems.

I have a class with a property of type

```
Action<Action<string,int>> myAction
```

and I want to assign it with a Lambda expression. I can do it without Lambda expressions using real methods that I have elsewhere in the code. I can also do something simple like

```
myAction = ((a) => { a("a string", 0); });
```

but I would like to asign the sub-action and the action in one Lambda. Something like...

```
myAction = (((s,i)=>{//sub-action body here})=> { //do something here});
```

But this syntax doesn't work. Is there a way to do this, or do I have to define my methods in advance and do it without a Lambda expression if I want to do this?

Comment: The sub-action is passed to the action as an input parameter, I don't understand to what you'd like to assign it.

Comment: I've had to think a lot about why I can't just do that. The answer is that I'm calling a method (not shown above) that has no parameters, but invokes the method stored in the 'myAction' property. myAction needs to know what s & i parameters to pass to the sub-action. In most cases where I use this myAction and the subaction are defined in different places and are fully written out as methods, but in this place I need to define the two together and was hoping to use lambda expressions to keep that succinct and avoid writing out full methods. Tsayper's solution below seems to get what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        Action<Action<string, int>> myAction = a => (new Action<string, int>((s, i) => Console.WriteLine(i + s)))("hello", 1);
        myAction(null);  //1hello
        Console.ReadLine();
```

though its equal to

```
        Action<Action<string, int>> myAction = a => Console.Writeline("1hello");
```

you just ignore an argument

Comment: Thank you :) I'm pretty sure this is what I'm looking for. I've run lots of tests with the rest of my code and it seems to be behaving as I want. Yes in your example it can be simplified but in my case the behaviour I want needs something similar to the first example you have given. I'm just running some more tests, but I think this will be the accepted answer once I've done that.

Comment: I'm now thinking it IS as simple as your simplified example. As I'm specifying both in the same place it makes sense to specify myAction simply. I have the two actions to allow them to be defined separately, but in this case the two levels are not needed, so this solution just effectively ignores the sub-action and myAction does it all instead. On the other hand if I wanted to just put values in the s & i parameters using the lambda (and not overwrite the sub-action) I can use the middle line of code from my question. Thanks for helping me boil down my requirement to the simplest form :)